# Output of Google Analytics reports of my site

Tags: rss, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a website that using google analytics for statistics.
I want to show my top posts in last month in my blog.
Can I have an output of its in rss or xml format?

Comment: As @shanabus suggests, use the Google Analytics API.  Or check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com "EmbeddedTopContent" widget.  This is a service which utilizes the GA API.  And it has features such as notification when new pages make the list (and you can accept or decline).  disclosure: I work with them.

Answer (score 3):

I am familiar with two ways of making this happen.

1. You could implement the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/) and export the data in the desired format
2. You could schedule exports of that data in CSV format and have it sent to an email inbox.  Then either manually or through some automated routine, pull the CSV attachment and publish it to your site.

I hope this helps get you going.